# doCmd.OpenReport where-condition syntax

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vba, report, ms-access-2010

I have a very small Access database where I'd like to have a button, which opens up a report ("Mitarbeiterhonorare") filtered by a chosen value in the combination field "Kf-Referentenname". Unfortunately, my where-condition just doesn't seem to work (there has to be some formatting mistake, since it just opens up an empty report). Can anybody help me with the syntax there?

Thanks a lot!

```vb
Private Sub cmdOpenReport_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.Kf_Referentenname) Then
        Me.Kf_Referentenname.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Bitte einen Mitarbeiter auswählen!", vbExclamation
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="Mitarbeiterhonorare",      View:=acViewPreview, _
            WhereCondition:=Referent_Name = "& Me.Kf_Referentenname"
    End If
End Sub
```

The query the report is based on Looks like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Honorare.Betrag) AS Gesamtbetrag_Honorare, Mitarbeiter.Referent_Name FROM Mitarbeiter INNER JOIN Honorare ON Mitarbeiter.Mitarbeiter_ID = Honorare.Mitarbeiter_ID GROUP BY Honorare.Mitarbeiter_ID, Mitarbeiter.Referent_Name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't even compile *, the double quotes are wrong.

`WhereCondition` must be a string:

```vb
   DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="Mitarbeiterhonorare", View:=acViewPreview, _
        WhereCondition:="Referent_Name = " & Me.Kf_Referentenname
```

and then `Referent_Name` is probably a text field, so you need additional quotes around the parameter:

```vb
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="Mitarbeiterhonorare", View:=acViewPreview, _
        WhereCondition:="Referent_Name = '" & Me.Kf_Referentenname & "'"
```

---

(*) Do you have [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of your module?

It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.
This is really a must have for VBA development.